# Why is DMS converting a single quote (') to (...) in Redshift?

Tags: oracle, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

I am using AWS DMS to migrate data from Oracle to Redshift. I am having issues with this column: MID_NM. In oracle this column is:

`MID_NM VARCHAR2(40)`

In Redshift I created the same table and converted that column's datatype to:

`mid_nm VARCHAR(40)   ENCODE lzo`

But when I run the migration task, it attempt to convert the original text in the Oracle column, which is:

`JAMES POLISH POLISHE GRANDCHILD’S FALSE` (39 characters)

to this:

`JAMES POLISH POLISHE GRANDCHILD...S FALSE` (41 characters)

It's wrong because both fields in Oracle and Redshift can only hold 40 characters. Since the apostrophe/quote is being converted to elipses (...) it exceeds the character limit in Redshift. I don't know how to fix this? Why is it doing that? Is it the "ENCODE lzo" thing? I tried adding a DMS transformation rule to alter the column to `string` so maybe it'll convert the original text to a literal string and not try to convert anything...it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that the character in the Oracle is not an apostrophe but a right single quote.  An apostrophe is ASCII x27 but a right single quote is x2019 which in multibyte UTF-8 needs 3 bytes to be represented. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

In Redshift varchar data type lengths are in bytes, not characters.  So for these multi-byte characters more space in the varchar is needed.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Supported_data_types.html

I suspect that the '...' is coming from a logging table that is using each dot to represent a non-ascii byte in the string.  So you will likely need to increase the varchar length to account for these multi-byte characters in the data.  The size increase shouldn't be much (1.25X) if there are only a few non-ascii characters in any string.  If you are dealing with strings that can have mostly non-ascii characters then the size may need to increase significantly (up to 4X).

To know exactly how much additional space you will need you can load the data into a temp table with a long varchar length specified and then compare MAX(LENGHT(MID_NM)) with MAX(OCTET_LENGTH(MID_NM)) - Octet_length() gives the length of a string in bytes where length() gives the length in characters.  The octet_length gives you how long the varchar column needs to be to store the information.

You could just 4X all varchar columns in your tables and not run into this any more BUT doing this has performance implications.  While data is compressed on disk (LZO in your case), a running query must allocate enough memory to store the largest possible string for each row of the table.  So 4X-ing the varchar size is going to waste space in memory for running queries.  Is this impact measurable? - that depends on how close to max memory your cluster is running and how large are your varchar columns.

A compromise is to 2X all varchar columns where user entered data could have multi-byte characters and stay at 1X for system defined data that cannot have multi-byte characters.  This is still wasteful on space but doesn't require a lot of data analysis to know the correct size.  This solution is still exposed to some possible data size issue but they should be very rare - like someone putting all symbols into a field.  You may want to up this to 3X if you expect to have user input on rarer character sets - Thai for example.

Another solution is to map all the data to ascii prior to loading to Redshift.  If all you are dealing with is a few characters (like right single quote or accented letters) then this mapping can be done with little loss of information and no need to change the table DDL.

Comment: Possibly the OP's database is using an older character set, like WE8MSWIN1252, where the right single quote is a single byte. He can run `select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';` to determine his Oracle database character set. Maybe DMS has problems converting between the character sets (although when that happens there is usually an upside-down question mark displayed).